# export partial component in React functional component

Tags: reactjs, import, components, export, partial

In the below code I don't want to export Carousel and I just want to import everything except Carousel in other component.

```
import React from "react";

function Navbar() {

};

return (
  <div className="navlabar">
    <div className="brand_name_logo">
      <Link to="/">
        <img src={brand_name} alt="brand_logo" />
      </Link>
    </div>
    <div className="dropdown">
      <div>
        <div id="explore__dropdown" className=" hide__ani hide__content">
          <div className="explore__all__project">
            <img src={exploreallproject}></img>
          </div>
          <div className="explore__top__10__find">
            <img src={top10find}></img>
          </div>
        </div>

        <Carousel climber1="CLMBR" />
      </div>
  );
}

export default Navbar;
```

Comment: return statement should be inside function

Comment: What is a partial component? If you want to export and use `Navbar` then you need to compose it in such a way that it doesn't render the `Carousel` component directly. Your snippet isn't valid JSX; the `return` needs to be *in* the component, and you've a missing closing `div` tag for `className="navlabar"`.